# Letter opener web returns Errno::ENOENT on dev env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, devise, rubygems

In rails, I'm building a confirmable method for users when they sign-up with Devise Confirmable model. To check to see the letters drop in the inbox I installed the letter opener web gem and followed all the instructions here for [letter opener web gem](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web). We are using rails 7 and ruby 3.1 versions and running docker. And when I navigate to /mail, I get this error

[Errno::ENOENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHmPg.png)

Checked the letters with `ls tmp/letter_opener` if they are populated and I can confirm that all the folders are there.

How can I fix this error? Not sure what am I missing here. Thank you sincerely for all the help already.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running this command `open tmp/letter_opener` and I can confirm that the file on the error page that was missing was actually in tmp/letter_opener folder. But contents of that the mail folder 1665782476_873833_996e302 was empty and rails was looking for a .html file in there so that's why it was erroring out. I cleaned everything in the tmp/letter_opener folder and navigated to /mail and could successfully render the letter opener web interactive view.